# New tab after clicking a link

Tags: popup-ads

I recently visited a website and I clicked a link suddenly a new tab appears about a survey. Was that a virus?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chromium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable Pop-Ups.  Just click on Customize and control --> Settings

[image]

Click on Show advanced settings

[image]

Then Privacy --> content settings

[image]

Then Pop-ups --> Do not allow

[image]

Also go to Customize and control --> Settings --> Extensions, and search for Ad Block, and choose an item from the list.

[image]

Comment: My default setting is like that. That reminds me of a site I visited and It was blocked but I tried it again and it was not blocked. Then, recently I visited kickasstorrent and it didn't block.

Comment: See added info in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I added an extension. Uhh instead of searching on google, I should have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

No it probably was just the website opening a new tab, which although annoying doesn't have to mean you got a virus;)

Comment: So, it's just ok to visit torrent sites and other stuffs? You can call me paranoid guy for this question.

Comment: @Jay-ar - keep an ad blocker active if you must visit such sites.

Comment: I searched about that weeks ago and here it's: [link] (http://penguininside.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-setup-chromium-google-chrome.html) I'm skeptical about the instructions.

Comment: Well there is a difference between doing all sorts of crazy stuff on the internet and having a single website spawn an extra tab in your browser. For general internet safety I use a combination of Adblock and Ghostery. That tutorial seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: Yeah, It's really complicated that's why I didn't do it. What browser are you using? The crazy stuff I am talking about is visiting nude photos. Lol

Comment: I really don't need to know what you're doing on the interwebs. But I suggest you just go to the chromium web store and search for adblock plus and ghostery there, no tutorial required. I use good old firefox myself though.